# Is it possible to code a switch-case statement

Tags: r, switch-statement, control-flow

Is it possible to write your own flow control functions in R? For instance, say we wanted to write a case type statement. Which sets a value then checks if the contents conform to the case value:

```
expo <- function (x,a) {
 case(a)
 C(1) return(x)
 C(2) return(x^2)
 C(3) return(x^3)
 C(%in% c(4,5) return(x^5)
}

expo(2,1)
[2]
expo(2,2)
[4]
expo(2,3)
[8]
expo(2,4)
[32]
```

Comment: You cannot write your own flow controls, only functions. For something similar, see the `swtich()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to control the work flow.

```
expo <- function(x, a) {
  switch(a,
         "1" = x,
         "2" = x^2,
         "3" = x^3,
         "4" = x^5,
         "5" = x^5)
}
expo(2, 4)


expo2 <- function(x, a) {
  if (a == 1) return(x)
  if (a == 2) return(x^2)
  if (a == 3) return(x^3)
  if (any(a %in% c(4, 5))) return(x^5)
}
expo2(2,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the 2 from Roman, here is a third:

```
expo3 <- function (x,a) {
  switch(a,
  x,x^2,x^3,x^5,x^5)
}
```

Here 'a' is an integer, and it will evaluate the corresponding element it the list of possible returns. That is if a=2, then it will return 'x^2', and if a is 4 or 5 it will return 'x^5'. Note that is you enter something like `expo(2,7)` it will return NULL.